# finding the most recent build number in a huge text

Tags: c#

hi i have a huge text file but i need to find the latest version(build number) and retrieve it to set it as a variable.

my text file:

```
...
sinsscm01:/mobile/6.70_Extensions/6.70.102/ANT_SASE_RELEASE_6.70.102.001
sinsscm01:/mobile/6.70_Extensions/6.70.102/ANT_SASE_RELEASE_6.70.102.002
sinsscm01:/mobile/6.70_Extensions/6.70.102/ANT_SASE_RELEASE_6.70.102.003
sinsscm01:/mobile/6.70_Extensions/6.70.102/ANT_SASE_RELEASE_6.70.102.004
sinsscm01:/mobile/6.70_Extensions/6.70.102/ANT_SASE_RELEASE_6.70.102.005
sinsscm01:/mobile/6.70_Extensions/6.70.102/ANT_SASE_RELEASE_6.70.102.006
sinsscm01:/mobile/6.70_Extensions/6.70.102/ANT_SASE_RELEASE_6.70.102.006
sinsscm01:/mobile/6.70_Extensions/6.70.102/ANT_SASE_RELEASE_6.70.102.006
sinsscm01:/mobile/6.70_Extensions/6.70.102/ANT_SASE_RELEASE_6.70.102.007
sinsscm01:/mobile/6.70_Extensions/6.70.102/ANT_SASE_RELEASE_6.70.102.008
sinsscm01:/mobile/6.70_Extensions/6.70.102/ANT_SASE_RELEASE_6.70.102.009
sinsscm01:/mobile/6.70_Extensions/6.70.102/ANT_SASE_RELEASE_6.70.102.010
sinsscm01:/mobile/6.70_Extensions/6.70.102/ANT_SASE_RELEASE_6.70.102.011
sinsscm01:/mobile/6.70_Extensions/6.70.102/ANT_SASE_RELEASE_6.70.102.012
sinsscm01:/mobile/6.70_Extensions/6.70.102/ANT_SASE_RELEASE_6.70.102.013
...
```

how should i go about finding the biggest build number? suppose that in this case 6.70.102.013 is the biggest build number.

so far what i did is:

```
    string abc = "sinsscm01:/mobile/6.70_Extensions/6.70.102/ANT_SASE_RELEASE_6.70.102.001";
    if (procOutput.Contains(abc))
    {
       // i am stuck here
    }
```

where procOutput is currently StandardOutput.ReadToEnd(). I thus saved a textfile using Textwriter from StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()

Comment: Are those build numbers ordered, i.e. the biggest is on the button?

Comment: yes, biggest is at the bottom. smallest at the top.

Comment: @Andy Johnson im in the middle of solving a huge problem involving this and many other issues, therefore i cant accept anything as of yet. I only work 3days a week, hence im sorry if i am slow to accept any solutions

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
string string greatestVersionNumber = ""
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path)) 
{
    while (sr.Peek() >= 0) 
    {
        var line = sr.ReadLine());
        var versionNumber = line.Replace(
            @"sinsscm01:/mobile/6.70_Extensions/6.70.102/ANT_SASE_RELEASE_", "");
        if(versionNumber.Length != line.Length)
            greatestVersionNumber = versionNumber;
    }
}
```

`greatestVersionNumber` will contain "6.70.102.013", even if there are lines with unrelated text in between or after the line with the version numbers.
There is only one condition:
The line with the greates version number must be the last of the version number lines.

Comment: if my text file contains other lines after "sinsscm01:/mobile/6.70_Extensions/6.70.102/ANT_SASE_RELEASE_6.70.102.013" then this will not work?

Comment: @jeremychan: Please see updated answer. This code will also work in these circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the following code snippet:

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path))
{
   var text = reader.ReadToEnd();
   var buildNo = text.SubString(text.Length - BuildNumberStringLength - 1, BuildNumberStringLength);
}
```

Comment: hi what is meant by BuildNumberStringLength?

Answer (score 0):

Read all the lines and extract each build number in turn. Convert it to an int by removing the periods and compare it to the current known highest. If higher, retain the build number.

```
using System.IO;

// ...

using(StreamReader rdr = new StreamReader(@"C:\myfile.txt"))
{
    const string marker = "ANT_SASE_RELEASE_";
    string maxBuildLabel = "";
    int maxBuildNum = int.MinValue;

    string line;
    while((line = rdr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        int i = line.IndexOf(marker);
        string buildLabel = line.Substring(i + marker.Length);
        int buildNum = int.Parse(buildLabel.Replace(".", ""));
        if (buildNum > maxBuildNum)
        {
            maxBuildLabel = buildLabel;
            maxBuildNum = buildNum;
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine(maxBuildLabel);
}
```

I haven't tried compiling this code, but it should indicate one possible solution.

**EDIT**

Fixed a couple of syntax errors and verified that the algorithm worked (it did).

Comment: hi andy johnson, i am currently using VS2008 with .netframework 3.5 there are alot of errors that im getting when i try to compile. such as `int.MinVal`

Comment: Jeremy - I should have known better than to post code without compiling it :)  I have updated the code above to fix two syntax errors. `int.MinVal` should be `int.MinValue`, and `marker` was defined as `string const` when it should be `const string`. I also added `using System.IO`, which was missing. I compiled it and ran it against your data and verified that it works.

Comment: I just noticed that you say the highest build number is always on the last line. This really reduces them problem to: 1. Find the last line, and 2. extract the build number from that line. The code I posted is a bit more generalized, in that it will also work if the lines are in any order. This may be inefficient if the data file is extremely large, in which case there is a more efficient way to do step 1.

Answer (score 0):

**There is a complete code for you that i wrote now:It is based on Regular Expression and Lambda**

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Program
{
        static IEnumerable<int> getBuildVersions(string BuildVersion)
        {
            string[] BuildVersionParts = BuildVersion.Split('.');
            foreach (string part in BuildVersionParts)
            {
                yield return int.Parse(part);
            }
        }

        static T[] HierarchicalMax<T>(IEnumerable<T[]> items)
        {
            var length = items.Min(v => v.Length);
            IEnumerable<T[]> result = items;

            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            {
                int offset = i;
                result = result.OrderByDescending(v => v[offset]);
            }

            T[] max = result.FirstOrDefault();

            return max;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string data = @"
                sinsscm01:/mobile/6.70_Extensions/6.70.102/ANT_SASE_RELEASE_6.70.102.001
sinsscm01:/mobile/6.70_Extensions/6.70.102/ANT_SASE_RELEASE_6.70.102.002
sinsscm01:/mobile/6.70_Extensions/6.70.102/ANT_SASE_RELEASE_6.70.102.003
sinsscm01:/mobile/6.70_Extensions/6.70.102/ANT_SASE_RELEASE_6.70.102.004
sinsscm01:/mobile/6.70_Extensions/6.70.102/ANT_SASE_RELEASE_6.70.102.005
sinsscm01:/mobile/6.70_Extensions/6.70.102/ANT_SASE_RELEASE_6.70.102.006
sinsscm01:/mobile/6.70_Extensions/6.70.102/ANT_SASE_RELEASE_6.70.102.006
sinsscm01:/mobile/6.70_Extensions/6.70.102/ANT_SASE_RELEASE_6.70.102.006
sinsscm01:/mobile/6.70_Extensions/6.70.102/ANT_SASE_RELEASE_6.70.102.007
sinsscm01:/mobile/6.70_Extensions/6.70.102/ANT_SASE_RELEASE_6.70.102.008
sinsscm01:/mobile/6.70_Extensions/6.70.102/ANT_SASE_RELEASE_6.70.102.009
sinsscm01:/mobile/6.70_Extensions/6.70.102/ANT_SASE_RELEASE_6.70.102.010
sinsscm01:/mobile/6.70_Extensions/6.70.102/ANT_SASE_RELEASE_6.70.102.011
sinsscm01:/mobile/6.70_Extensions/6.70.102/ANT_SASE_RELEASE_6.70.102.012
sinsscm01:/mobile/6.70_Extensions/6.70.102/ANT_SASE_RELEASE_6.70.102.013
";
            List<int[]> BuildVersions = new List<int[]>();

            Regex rx = new Regex(@"\d+\.+\d+\.+\d+\d+\.+\d+");

            foreach (Match m in rx.Matches(data))
            {                
                BuildVersions.Add(getBuildVersions(m.Value).ToArray());                
            }

            foreach (int[] version in BuildVersions)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(version[0].ToString() + " " + version[1].ToString() + " " + version[2].ToString() + " " + version[3].ToString());
            }

            int[] maxVersion = HierarchicalMax<int>(BuildVersions);

            Console.WriteLine("MaxVersion is ");
            Console.WriteLine(maxVersion[0].ToString() + " " + maxVersion[1].ToString() + " " + maxVersion[2].ToString() + " " + maxVersion[3].ToString());

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
 }
```